# Can we place Information icon inside a Chip or Tag element?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, ux-field, human-interface-guideline

I am working on a popup screen. In this situation, the user attempts to publish a job on a certain job board, for example, Linkedin. The popup will open, and in order to publish a job, we must input a figure in the budget calculator that indicates how much we are willing to spend on the job. After calculating, the outcome will be an approximate number of how much Total applies, with Estimated Higher applied. My question is that I'm displaying the results as tag-like components with numbers, labels, and info icons. Can we place the information icon inside it.? Check the image below for reference. Thanks[image]

Comment: You can amend your existing question to add these details, but you shouldn't just repost the same question a second time.